# Run some action after changes commit

Tags: git

I have a Java Application. Everytime a change is made to self hosted git server, I need to curl a endpoint of the application inorder to reload the properties. Here is what my curl look like: `curl -X {} http://someurl:8080/abc`.

I would like to automate this after a commit is made. I have read about git and found that "post commit" should get the job done but after reading about it for more than 2 hours I gave up. I would like to create a script that will curl the endpoint when commit is made. The hosted server is a linux machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is also known as webhook. Here is how to achieve this.

First `cd .git/hooks` and create `post-commit` file. Eg: `touch post-commit`. Now run the following to make it executable:

```
chmod +x post-commit
```

Add the script to `post-commit` using `nano post-commit` (You can also write it in any other scripting language for eg python):

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -X {} http://someurl:8080/abc
```

Now when you commit the changes, `post-commit` will run automatically.

[Read more on git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Comment: Even I read git-scm but couldn't understand it. Thankyou for the explaination.

Answer (score 1):

A idea might be to use a `post-push` hook and put the curl command in there.
On every commit the script with the curl will be exexuted.

in `<project>/.git/hooks`

put a file called `post-push`, this should be a shell script with the command required.

usually i prefer these type of things to be done on push not on every commit

Comment: *I would like to automate this after a commit is made*